# what is exactly doing rm -r *

Tags: command-line-arguments, rm

Is someone can tell me what is exactly doing rm -r *

is it deleting all files and sub directory from current directory ?

or does it delete all the files on the machine ?

Comment: it does remove all the files in the current directory, and also the files in subdirectories.

Comment: `r` for *recursive*. See: [ss64 page](http://ss64.com/bash/rm.html).

Answer (score 0):

Deletes them all from the current directory, so it depends where you are at the time.

Do

```
pwd
```

to find out where you are - for example:

```
mark2@laptop-ubuntu:~$ pwd
/home/mark2
```

If I do it here, it'll delete everything under /home/mark2.